# How to do goquery selection based on multiple attributes

Tags: go, web-scraping, goquery

How do we scrape the text of a below div tag using goquery

`<div class="class_1" attr="attr_1">text</div>`

I tried with the below selection logic, but it didn't work

`divtag := doc.Find("div[class='class_1' attr='attr_1']")`

I couldn't find example for goquery selection based on multiple attributes as above. Does goquery provide such functionality? How should we scrape it?

Answer (score 0):

It was a syntax issue on selection, the below selection worked.

`divtag := doc.Find("div[class='class_1'][attr='attr_1']")`